# how to create load more bottom in nextjs for get rest of data? (Next.js Pagination)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to click on Load More bottom and get the rest of data in next.js how can do this?
in this page I'm using `getServerSideProps` to get data from api

My Page code is :

```
export default function Posts({ posts, popular }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <motion.main
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    >
      <InnerWrapper pbNone>
        <Title title="Latest Post" subTitle />
      </InnerWrapper>
      <HeroSection data={posts} />
      <InnerWrapper>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
            {posts.map(item => (
              <HorizontalCard key={item.id} info={item} />
            ))}

            <LoadMoreBtn />
            
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <div className={classes.marginBottom}>
              <Title title={"Most Popular"} subTitle side={true} />
              <SideList data={popular} />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.marginBottom}>
              <SubscribeSide />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </InnerWrapper>
    </motion.main>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const { data: posts } = await postLists(0);
  const { data: popular } = await popularPost();
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { posts, popular } };
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` is for getting data to be used for the first render. Unlike that, your "load more" button needs to work on the client-side.

I will try to summarize the steps you should take:

1. In order to be able to manipulate the posts that will be displayed, you need to store your items in the state, not props. So, create a state using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and fill it with the data coming from the props, something like this:

   ```js
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState(props.posts);
   ```

   From now on, you will use this `posts` variable instead of the one from the props.
2. Add the "load more" button. All loading more posts business logic should go to its `onClick` handler. Something like this:

   ```
   <button
     onClick={async () => {
        const newPosts = await getNewPostsFromApi();

        setPosts(...posts, ...newPosts);
     }}
     type="button"
   >
   Load more
   </button>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Just one question: shouldn't it be setPosts([...posts, ...newPosts]); instead of  setPosts(...posts, ...newPosts);?

Comment: @JoãoPaiva: props.posts is an array so you can distracture that like this
export default function Posts({ posts,}) and set setPosts([...posts, ...newPosts])

Comment: How does this affect SEO? Will Google be able to crawl those posts organically if they only show from state?

Comment: +1 about SEO. I need SSR for web crawlers to see the contents which means the component should be declared with `"use server";`. BUT server components don't allow `useState`, this one is for client components. So, what do we do here?

Comment: UPD: Just found out that websites add "&page=2" to the query params even for infinite scrolling lists or lists with "show more" button. So no need in `useState`: all state is in url.